# Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to find out how can I fix this problem

> Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")

So here's my code:

```
Sub SearchMacro ()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
With Sheets("M-List")
LR = .Range("T2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LR
    With .Range("T2" & i)
        If .Value = sheets("JAN!).Range("D158").Value = sheets("M-List").Range("N2").Value Then

        Sheets("M-List").Range("T2").Value = Sheets("JAN!").Range("H158").Value

        End If
    End With
 Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the missing ", there seems to be aproblem with a double assignation in your code

```
  If .Value = sheets("JAN!).Range("D158").Value = sheets("M-List").Range("N2").Value Then
```

If you are comparing  `M-List!T2#` (where # goes from 1 to X) to `JAN!D158`, then use this code

```
If .Value = sheets("JAN").Range("D158").Value Then`
```

But if you are comparing JAN!D158 = M-List!N2, then use this code

```
If sheets("JAN").Range("D158").Value = sheets("M-List").Range("N2").Value Then`
```

Comment: I insist in removing the ! from JAN! inside Sheets("")

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your first If statement, it should begin with `If .Value = sheets("JAN!")`

You have a missing double quote at the end of the sheet name.